# Plotting Weekly Data of Categorical Variables in R

Tags: r, plot, dataframe, time-series

I have a weekly data of three variables

```
W   Var Units
1   A   10
2   A   3
2   B   19
3   C   8
3   A   54
3   A   6
4   C   2
4   B   13
6   C   22
6   A   31
7   C   17
7   A   43
7   D   4
```

`I want to plot it in such way that on y-axis Var (i.e. A, B, C with different colors) should be plotted with Week number (W) on x-axis. A week (W) may contain two or three variables. For instance, third week has A as well as C. So week is multi valued function with units represent the size of point. So far I have used

```
ndf <- data.frame(W= 1:max(as.numeric(as.character(df$W))))
merge_df <- merge(df, ndf, all=TRUE) # to note every week number so that zeors can also be plotted
merge_df[is.na(merge_df)] <- 0 # setting Na's to zero
```

The problem is after these steps, some NA's are produced in Var column. How this can be handled and plotted?

Next thing this is a sample data and how this can be done if I have week numbers of 10 years and I want to plot Var as weekly time series of 10 years.

Comment: The NA's are showing up in the Var column because it is of the class `factor`. Zero is not one of the factors, so it is not being changed. Are you sure you want a zero in that slot instead of a letter?

Comment: Dear Pierre, it can easily be handled in the solution provided by Steven. Factor NA is no longer a disturbing part now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand your question, does this help ?

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggvis)

df %>%
  ggvis(~W, ~Var, fill = ~Var, size = ~Units)  %>%
  layer_points() %>%
  add_legend("size", properties = legend_props(legend = list(y = 100))) %>%
  scale_numeric("x", nice = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Steven, thanks for reply. It works almost good. How can this situation be tackled in five or ten years data?

Comment: @Pankaj You mean if you have identical week numbers for different years ?

Comment: not exactly. But yes with this pattern I can have data for different years

Comment: @Pankaj Please provide your desired output